# Cannot create HTML meta tags with name attribute in PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am writing a PowerShell script to add a meta tag to the head section of a HTML file. The tag must be as follows: <meta name=”robots” content=”noindex, nofollow”>.

The general snippet below works for all attributes, except for attributes called name:

```
$newMeta = $doc.createElement("meta")
$newMeta.attributename = "attribute content"
```

So this works:

```
$newMeta = $doc.createElement("meta")
$newMeta.content = "noindex, nofollow"
```

But this does not:

```
$newMeta = $doc.createElement("meta")
$newMeta.name = "robots"
```

The name attribute is just ignored in the output.

How can I add an attribute called name to the output?

Comment: What is `$doc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no more takers, so I will try to answer the question myself.
From what I understand, it is not possible to set an attribute called "name" on an HTML element, either with SetAttribute() or with a property (object.attributename).

I managed to obtain the same effect with a workaround: I first create an attribute with a placeholder name, then replace the placeholder name with the string "name".

I am aware that is not an elegant solution, and I am somewhat ashamed of it, but it works. Maybe the following snippet can be of help to others.

```
$file = "somefile.html"
$content = Get-Content $file -Raw

$doc = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$doc.IHTMLDocument2_write($content)

$meta = $doc.getElementsByName("robots") | Select-Object -First 1

if ($meta) {
    $meta.outerHTML = ""
    $doc.documentElement.outerHTML | Set-Content $file
}

$head = $doc.getElementsByTagName("head") | Select-Object -First 1
$newMeta = $doc.createElement("meta")
$newMeta.content = "noindex, nofollow"
#SetAttribute() cannot create an attribute named "name". 
#So instead I will give it a placeholder name and replace it later on.
$newMeta.SetAttribute('__nameee__', 'robots')
$newMeta.outerHTML | Add-Content $logFile
$head.appendChild($newMeta)
$doc.documentElement.outerHTML | Set-Content $file

$htmlContent = Get-Content $file -Raw

$pattern = "__nameee__"

if ($htmlContent -match $pattern) {
# Replace the placeholder attribute name with "name".
$htmlContent = $htmlContent -replace $pattern, "name"

# Overwrite the original HTML file with the updated content
    Set-Content $file -Value $htmlContent }
else {
    Write-Host "The HTML file $htmlFilePath does not contain a robots metatag."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$doc` is an `XmlDocument` object, this is a case of PowerShell's XML adapter having a conflict between the `Name` property on each xml node object, and the `name` attribute you want to add to the document itself.

Use the `SetAttribute()` method to unambiguously set an attribute value:

```
$newMeta.SetAttribute('name', 'robots')
```

---

```
PS ~> $doc = [xml]::new()
PS ~> $newMeta = $doc.CreateElement('meta')
PS ~> $newMeta.OuterXml
<meta />
PS ~> $newMeta.SetAttribute('name', 'robots')
PS ~> $newMeta.OuterXml
<meta name="robots" />
```

Comment: Hello Mathias, thank you, but SetAttribute() has exactly the same problem. The attribute does not get created.

Comment: @DiegoSchiavon Are you sure? How are you asserting that the attribute hasn't been created/set?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure. I had tried SetAttribute() before posting. But this: $newMeta = $doc.createElement("meta")
$newMeta.SetAttribute('name', 'robots')
$newMeta.content = "noindex, nofollow"
Results in this: <META content="noindex, nofollow">

Comment: @DiegoSchiavon I'm sure it does - that's expected - there's no `Content` property on the underlying type, so no conflict. What do you do _after_ calling `SetAttribute()`? What does `$newMeta.OuterXml` show you?

Comment: This is what happens to $newMeta:
$newMeta = $doc.createElement("meta")
$newMeta.SetAttribute('name', 'robots')
$newMeta.content = "noindex, nofollow"
$head.appendChild($newMeta)
$doc.documentElement.outerHTML | Set-Content $file
This: $newMeta.outerHTML | Add-Content $logFile prints this in the log file: <META content="noindex, nofollow">, the same as in the output $file.

Comment: @DiegoSchiavon You keep using `outerHTML` instead of `OuterXml`. What exactly is `$doc`?

Comment: $doc = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile" - the file is not valid XML so OuterXml will not work - but OuterHTML will.